# Are there any languages that use rapidly repeated or stammered/stuttered sounds for differentiation?

Tags: list-of-languages, phonotactics, phoneme-inventories

Ignoring languages such as spanish that distinguish between /ɾ/ and /r/, as such is not what I refer to, are there any languages that would differentiate between say, /p/ and /ppp/. It is a weird concept, but it is something that came to mind. I suppose, with the example I have in mind, the stammer would be realized as [pĭpĭpĭ], if that helps. Recalling back on the first, differentiating between /ɾ/ and /ɾĭɾĭɾĭ/ would be what I am referring to.

I suppose the simplest example would be languages such as latin that use(d) double consonants to differentiate. e.g. *anvs,* [anus] (ring) vs. *annvs,* /an.nus~anənʊs~anːus/ (year.)

Comment: I have never read of Latin having [nən] as an allophone of /nn~nː/. Why do you say it did?

Comment: That was creative liberty, because the two nasal plosives are pronounced separately. It kind of sounds like a schwa, but I know it is not.

Comment: But how do you know they were pronounced separately?  Or maybe you just mean that *you* pronounce them separately.

Comment: Technically we can't even be 100% sure that ⟨nn⟩ wasn't pronounced as /q/ in the most obscure dialects, but pronounced separately, I do pronounce them separately. I would imagine they merged into being pronounced as a single long consonant at some point. Creative liberty in expression. That is why I wrote /n.n/ then wrote /nə̆n/. I intended them to be the same pronunciation. I have never really thought of /nn/ like in the english "unnamed" as two separate consonants, but one that is being restressed -- that's why I prefer /n.n/ or /nə̆n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Gemination**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) of consonants (and long vowels) as a sound phonologically distinct from single consonants (or short vowels) is a feature common to many languages.

Here is a selection of minimal pairs of words distinguished by consonant length:

---

#### Cairene Arabic

- حَمَام `/ħa.maːm/` "dove; pigeon"
- حَمَّام `/ħam.maːm/` "bathroom"

**Note:** some pairs of words may appear to be minimal pairs orthographically, but often have different vowels:

- مدرسة `/mad.ra.sa/` "school"
- مدرّسة `/mu.dar.ri.sa/` "female teacher"

#### Berber

- *imi* `/imi/` "mouth"
- *immi* `/immi/` "mother"

#### Bengali

- আটা `/ˈät̺ä/` "flour"
- আটটা `/ˈät̺t̺ä/` "eight (of something)"

#### Catalan

- *gala* `/ˈɡa.ɫə/` "Show in a festival; party"
- *gal·la* `/ˈɡaɫ.ɫə/` "Gallic; Gaulish person (fem.)"

#### English

- *unaimed* `[ʌnˈeɪmd]`
- *unnamed* `[ʌnˈneɪmd]`

#### Finnish

- *takka* `[ˈtakːa]` / `[ˈtakka]` "fireplace"
- *taka* `[ˈtaka]` "back"

#### French

In French, consonant length is usually not distinctive, but in certain exceptional cases it can be:

- *courons* `[kuʁɔ̃]`
- *courrons* `[kuʁːɔ̃]`

#### Ganda / Luganda

- *-kapa* `/kapa/` "coarse" (suffix)
- *kkapa* `/kːapa/` "cat"

#### Ancient Greek

- μέλω `[mélɔː]` "I am of interest"
- μέλλω `[mélːɔː]` "I am going to"

#### Cypriot Greek

- πολύ `[poˈli]` "very"
- πολλοί `[polˈli]` "a lot"

#### Hindi; Urdu

- पता ; پتہ `/pəˈt̻ä/` "address"
- पत्ता ; پتہ `/pət̻ˈt̻ä/` "leaf"

#### Hungarian

- *megy* `[ˈmɛɟ]` "goes"
- *meggy* `[ˈmɛɟː]` "sour cherry"

#### Japanese

- 来た (きた, `/kita/`) "came; arrived"
- 切った (きった, `/kitta/`) "cut; sliced"

#### Polish

- *saki* `/saki/` "sacks, bags"
- *ssaki* `/sːaki/` "mammals"

#### Punjabi

- ਸਤ `[sət̪]` "truth" (liturgical)
- ਸੱਤ `[sət̪ː]` "seven"

#### Russian

- подержать `[pədʲɪrˈʐatʲ]` "to hold"
- поддержать `[pəddʲɪrˈʐatʲ]` "to support"

#### Turkish

- *ata* `/aˈta/` "predecessor; forefather"
- *atta* `/aˈtːa/` "horse" (singular locative)

#### Ukranian

- мана `mɑnɑ` "delusion"
- манна `mɑnnɑ` "manna; semolina"

---

Some languages even have examples of 3-way consonant length distinction:

#### Danish

- *bunde* `[b̥ɔnə]` "bottoms"
- *bundne* `[b̥ɔnnə]` "bound" (pl.)
- *bundene* `[b̥ɔnn̩nə]` "the bottoms"

#### Estonian

- *lina* `/linɑ/` "sheet" (short)
- *linna* `/linːɑ/` "town" [gen. sg.] (long)
- *linna* `/linːːɑ/` "town" [ine. sg.] (overlong)

---

**Note:** In the following languages, they are not true minimal pairs, since the stress shifts from the preceding vowel to the consonant giving a two-way distinction:

#### Standard Italian

- *beve* `/ˈbeːve/` "he/she drinks/is drinking"
- *bevve* `/ˈbevːe/` "he/she drank"

#### Latin

- *ānus* `/ˈaː.nus/` "ring; anus"
- *annus* `/ˈan.nus/` "year"

#### Norweigian

- *måte* `/moːtə/` "method"
- *måtte* `/motːə/` "had to"

#### Swedish

- *håla* `/'hoːla/`  "deep hole; cave"
- *hålla* `/'holːa/` "hold; grip"

---

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_phonology#Suprasegmental_length
- https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/gala
- [https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/gal·la](https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/gal%C2%B7la)
- [https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/hindi-english/पता](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/hindi-english/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE)
- [https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/hindi-english/पत्ता](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/hindi-english/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE)
- http://www.learnluganda.com/concise
- http://asegzawal.net/english/
- [*Phonetic Universals and Hindi Segment Duration*](http://www.linguistics.berkeley.edu/%7Eohala/papers/o_and_o_banff.pdf), Manjari Ohala & John J. Ohala
- [*We Share Walls: Language, Land, and Gender in Berber Morocco*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ThD6g5laZFYC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=Tamazight+immi), Katherine E. Hoffman
- [*Geminate representation in Arabic*](http://www.indiana.edu/%7Elingdept/faculty/davis/Davis_Ragheb_Geminate_Rep_Arabic_2014.pdf), Stuart Davis and Marwa Ragheb
- [*Gemination in Swedish & Arabic with a particular reference to the preceding vowel duration. An instrumental & comparative approach*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.202.8058&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Zeki M. Hassan
- [*Perception of consonant length: voiceless stops in Turkish and Bengali*](http://www.ling-phil.ox.ac.uk/files/hankamer.pdf), Jorge Hankame, Aditi Lahiri and Jacques Korenan

Comment: I seem to remember there was some Ugric language (was it Voro, or Pitesami?) which had as many as four length distinctions.

Comment: In Cherente, a S. American language, "a cough" is /da-kka/ (the /da-/ is a prefix used with a thing that is possessed).  Cherente is also spelled Xerente or Sherente.

Comment: Finno-Ugric transcription encompasses something like 8 length differences. Contrastiveness is a very different thing, and analysis is especially different. The most famous example is Estonian, which Lehiste has shown is not about 3 degrees of length, it's about two intersecting things which have a two-way distinction.

Comment: The Hindi example isn't a minimal pair. पता/پتہ (patā) has a laminal dento-alveolar plosive [t̻], while पट्टा/پٹہ (paṭṭā) has an apical post-alveolar/'retroflex' plosive [t̠~ʈ]. Also, I have never really heard of the word पट्टा/پٹہ for 'band', it is usually पट्टी/پٹی (paṭṭī). Instead, पता/پتہ (patā = address) contrasts with पत्ता/پتہ (pattā = leaf).

Comment: @ColinFine ah true, I will amend the answer to clarify. There are a few others that are only minimal pairs in some dialects, and are further distinguished by vowel quality in others.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache thanks for the correction! My knowledge of Hindi is very minimal, I will replace my example with yours.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache Not at all - thanks :)

Comment: If you're looking for minimal pairs, strike Luganda (-kapa is a bound root, requires and agreement prefix, so there is a prefix like omu- etc. before. Norwegian requires some argumentation: gemination is predictable, if vowel length is phonemic.

Comment: In at least the Swedish and Japanese examples, the double consonants denote short vowels, rather than stammering.